# jQuery selector custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have elements in my page like

```
<div class="editableTxt" data-model-attr="name" data-model-id="123">some text</div>
```

Now how do I write a selector in jQuery based on the 2 custom attribute values.
So i want something like select element with data-model-attr="name" data-model-id="123"

I want to get a unique element. So I use the 2 attributes.

Comment: `$('div[data-model-attr="name"][data-model-id="123"]')`

Comment: as long as its within the same set of inverted commas, you are good.

Comment: @testndtv why don't you give response to none of the below answers?

Answer (score 0):

USe like this

```
$("[data-model-attr='name'][data-model-id='123']")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you specified element and not `div`, have you simply tried:

```
$('[data-model-attr="name"][data-model-id="123"]');
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/x23BV/

for a div obviously just add `div`:

```
$('div[data-model-attr="name"][data-model-id="123"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('div[data-model-attr="name"][data-model-id="123"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[data-model-attr="name"][data-model-id="123"]')
```

But **don't use it**, it's very slow, set id or classes to this `div`.